# Google Data studio encode my Arabic titles in landingpage reports table

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, data, google-data-studio

Google Data studio encode my Arabic titles in landing-page reports table, when my data source is "Search Console URL":

[image]

in other hand hand when I gather data from "Analytics" data source it shows correctly:

[image]

I try blended data source it means gather landing-page titles from analytics and gathering impression and clicks data from search console URL, but not working, I think blended data source is not for this.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Using international characters in URLs requires that they have two forms.
URLs can only have ASCII characters in them according to the spec.   International characters have to be encoded using percent encoded UTF-8 values.  Browsers show users the international characters in address bar, but send the encoded URLs to the server.   If you copy and paste the URL out of the address bar, it will also have the encoded value.  I'm not sure how to get these tools that each prefer a different form to talk to each other.

Comment: Not sure if the following is helpful to you, I've used punycode in the past with other thing that have required urls with ASCII characters where international characters have been used
https://www.punycoder.com/